# How do i do a do-while loop?

Tags: java, do-while

I am working on improving my do-while loop skills and i am kind of stuck trying to implement a do-while loop which loops everytime the word bye is not found.

```
   public static void getinput() throws IOException {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
    /* End Initialization */

    System.out.println("Welcome ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");
  do{
    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    parseFile(input);

    System.out.println("is there anything you want to know?");
    }
  while(input.contains("bye")
 {
 System.out.println("have a good day");
  }
```

can someone assist me with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks like this:

```
do{
   System.out.print("> ");
   input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
   parseFile(input);

   System.out.println("is there anything you want to know?");
} while(input.contains("bye"); // Semicolon after the "while." This is the end of the statement
// No brackets here. 
System.out.println("have a good day");
```

However, note that this will continue to loop as long as the user is saying "bye" (perhaps you want `while (!input.contains("bye"))`)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
while(input.contains("bye")
```

is missing a semicolon and should be testing the opposite case, and the code after that line does not need to be enclosed in brackets. Otherwise your code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I beieve you are looking for something like,

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "";
System.out.println("Welcome ");
System.out.println("What would you like to know?");
do {
    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    parseFile(input);

    System.out.println("is there anything you want to know?");
} while (!input.startsWith("bye")); // <-- while it doesn't...
System.out.println("have a good day");
```

Comment: when i enter "bye" the program does not exit

Answer (score 0):

do while syntax
do {
     statement(s)
} while (expression);
Your Code
     public static void getinput() throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = null;
        /* End Initialization */

```
    System.out.println("Welcome ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");
  do{
    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    parseFile(input);
    System.out.println("is there anything you want to know?");
    }
  while(input.contains("bye"));//right parenthesis add semicolon 
                         OR 
  while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"));
//remove braces from here.
 System.out.println("have a good day");
```